# Show mobile code for country based on machine culture setting

Tags: c#

I want to read culture of machine and would like show country Mobile code
in text box. For example if someone is opening site for India then +91 should
be visible in Mobile text.

Can any one suggest me code for the same using c#.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually working on something similar to this - at the moment the only thing I can think of is something like this -

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the dialling code.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="culture">The culture.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string RetrieveDiallingCode(string culture)
    {
        string value = "+44";
        switch (culture)
        {
            case "sv-SE":
                value = "+46";
                break;
            case "de-DE":
                value = "+49";
                break;
            case "fr-FR":
                value = "+33";
                break;
            case "fi-FI":
                value = "+358";
                break;
            case "en-US":
                value = "+1";
                break;
            default:
                value = "+44";
                break;
        }

        return value;
    }
```

And then retrieve it like so

```
  RetrieveDiallingCode(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)
```

Unfortunately, its a bit tacky because its hardcoded - but you could always add them to an xml file and retrieve them from there. I got a list of the codes from this site:

http://wikitravel.org/en/List_of_country_calling_codes